# I got some problems with 2 programs im working on

Tags: c

i have been working on 2 programs:

```
    void neg_zero(char* x)
{
    if (*x < 0)
    {
        x = 0;
    }
}
```

this code above men't to check if a char that x point to is negative and if is negative the code will zero x.

second code:

```
    void weirdFunc(int* a, int * b) {
    **if (a == b)**
    {
        **a = a + b;**
    }
    else
    {
        **b = a - b;**
    }
}
void main() {
    int a = 0, y=0;
    int* x = NULL;
    x = &a;
    a = 6;
    y = 5;
    **weirdFunc(x, y);**
    **printf("%d \n%d \n", x, y);** 
}
```

this function receive two pointers to int and them like that:
if the two numbers equals it puts in the first parameter their combining.
if the two numbers are different it put in the second parameters their difference.

now the second function made in a very specific demand so if you can change only the marker'd parts (**).

Thank you all!

Comment: You have two unrelated questions. So split them into two different questions.

Comment: `x = 0;` in the first function does virtually nothing because `x` will be discarded just after that. Are you sure you want to zero `x`, not what is pointed at by `x`?

Comment: `weirdFunc` is weird, so the implementation is "correct", but the arguments passed is wrong. Use correct type! You should pass pointers to wherever pointers are expected. Also note that passing `int*` to `%d` of `printf()` invokes *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first function is correct because it does "the code will zero x". If you happened to want to zero *what is pointed by `x`*, change `x = 0;` to `*x = 0;`.

Using correct types and dereferencing, the second code should be like this:

```
    void weirdFunc(int* a, int * b) {
    if (*a == *b)
    {
        *a = *a + *b;
    }
    else
    {
        *b = *a - *b;
    }
}
void main() {
    int a = 0, y=0;
    int* x = NULL;
    x = &a;
    a = 6;
    y = 5;
    weirdFunc(x, &y);
    printf("%d \n%d \n", *x, y);
}
```

I'm very very sorry that I can't correct issues that proper header is not included and non-standard `void main()` is used due to the resrtiction.